# AND statement failing inside IF statement but works when used separately

Tags: excel-formula

I have the below formula that does not work:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(data[Ticket No.], SMALL(IF(AND(data[SLA (Hrs)]>=-24,data[SLA (Hrs)]<0), ROW(data[SLA (Hrs)])-ROW(Data!$D$2)+1), ROW(1:1))),"No Match")
```

When I remove the AND and just use either of the criteria, the formula works:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(data[Ticket No.], SMALL(IF(data[SLA (Hrs)]>=-24, ROW(data[SLA (Hrs)])-ROW(Data!$D$2)+1), ROW(1:1))),"No Match")

=IFERROR(INDEX(data[Ticket No.], SMALL(IF(data[SLA (Hrs)]<0, ROW(data[SLA (Hrs)])-ROW(Data!$D$2)+1), ROW(1:1))),"No Match")
```

When I test the AND statement on it's own, it returns TRUE.

```
AND(data[SLA (Hrs)]>=-24,data[SLA (Hrs)]<0)
```

The full formula outputs:

It returns 1 'Ticket No.' with 'SLA (Hrs)' of -2000 which is incorrect.

I have 10 'Ticket No.' with 'SLA (Hrs)' between -24 and 0 in the 'data' table.

Any insight anyone can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards,

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array formulas do not work with `AND()` or `OR()`  Use `*` or `+` respectively.

> `AND(data[SLA (Hrs)]>=-24,data[SLA (Hrs)]<0)`

Should be:

```
(data[SLA (Hrs)]>=-24)*(data[SLA (Hrs)]<0)
```

so:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(data[Ticket No.], SMALL(IF((data[SLA (Hrs)]>=-24)*(data[SLA (Hrs)]<0), ROW(data[SLA (Hrs)])-ROW(Data!$D$2)+1), ROW(1:1))),"No Match")
```

remember to Confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.

Comment: I was unaware of the AND/OR not working in array formulae.

Thank you for your help. Saves me a massive headache!